# Ember attaching a RESTAdaptor: error on <Ember.Route:ember325> / Error while loading route followed by massive dump of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to Ember and getting this massive and somewhat cryptic error when moving from the Fixture Adaptor to the REST Adaptor. No other code changes were made other than commenting out my fixture data.

my code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

// App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://192.168.1.193:8080',
  namespace: '/serviceprovidersservice/rest'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("service_providers", function() {
    this.route("new");
    this.route("edit", { path: 'edit/:id' });
  });

  this.resource("customers", function() {
    this.route("new");
    this.route("edit", { path: 'edit/:id' });
  });
});

// Routes

App.ServiceProvidersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('ServiceProvider');
    }
});

App.ServiceProvidersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('ServiceProvider');
    }
});

App.ServiceProvidersEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('ServiceProvider', params.id);
    }
});

App.CustomersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('Customer');
    }
});

App.CustomersEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('Customer', params.id);
    }
});

App.CustomersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return {
            serviceproviders : this.store.find('ServiceProvider')
        };
    }
})

// Controllers

App.ServiceProvidersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions : {
        create: function() {
            name = this.get("name");
            if (!name.trim()) { return; }
            email = this.get("email");

            sp = this.store.createRecord('ServiceProvider', {
                name: name,
                email: email
            });
            sp.save();
            this.set('name', '');
            this.set('email', '');
            this.transitionToRoute("service_providers.edit", sp);
        }
    }
});

App.ServiceProvidersEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});

App.CustomersEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});

App.CustomersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    selectedServiceProvider : null,
    actions : {
        create: function() {
            firstname = this.get("firstname");
            lastname = this.get("lastname");
            if (!firstname.trim()) { return; }
            email = this.get("email");
            serviceprovider = this.get("selectedServiceProvider");
            sp = this.store.createRecord('Customer', {
                firstname: firstname,
                lastname: lastname,
                email: email,
                serviceprovider: serviceprovider
            });
            sp.save();
            this.set('name', '');
            this.set('email', '');
            this.transitionToRoute("customers.edit", sp);
        }
    }
});

// Models

App.Customer = DS.Model.extend({
    serviceprovider: DS.belongsTo('serviceProvider'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ServiceProvider = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    customers: DS.hasMany('customer', {async:true})
});
```

The errors:

```
[15:46:25.144] DEPRECATION: Action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in favor of putting them in an `actions` object (error on <Ember.Route:ember325>)
    trigger@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:29641
    handleError@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:29903
    invokeCallback@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8055
    Promise.prototype.then/<@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8109
    EventTarget.trigger@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:7878
    reject/<@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:8180
    DeferredActionQueues.prototype.flush@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5459
    Backburner.prototype.end@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5545
    Backburner.prototype.run@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5584
    Ember.run@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:5915
    Ember.EventDispatcher<._bubbleEvent@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:19034
    Ember.EventDispatcher<.setupHandler/</<@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:18978
    Ember.handleErrors@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:555
    Ember.EventDispatcher<.setupHandler/<@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/ember-1.0.0.js:18984
    jQuery.event.dispatch@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
    jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
[15:46:25.144] Error while loading route: ({readyState:0, getResponseHeader:(function ( key ) {
                    var match;
                    if ( state === 2 ) {
                        if ( !responseHeaders ) {
                            responseHeaders = {};
                            while ( (match = rheaders.exec( responseHeadersString )) ) {
                                responseHeaders[ match[1].toLowerCase() ] = match[ 2 ];
                            }
                        }
                        match = responseHeaders[ key.toLowerCase() ];
                    }
                    return match == null ? null : match;
                }), getAllResponseHeaders:(function () {
                    return state === 2 ? responseHeadersString : null;
                }), setRequestHeader:(function ( name, value ) {
                    var lname = name.toLowerCase();
                    if ( !state ) {
                        name = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] || name;
                        requestHeaders[ name ] = value;
                    }
                    return this;
                }), overrideMimeType:(function ( type ) {
                    if ( !state ) {
                        s.mimeType = type;
                    }
                    return this;
                }), statusCode:(function ( map ) {
                    var code;
                    if ( map ) {
                        if ( state < 2 ) {
                            for ( code in map ) {
                                // Lazy-add the new callback in a way that preserves old ones
                                statusCode[ code ] = [ statusCode[ code ], map[ code ] ];
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Execute the appropriate callbacks
                            jqXHR.always( map[ jqXHR.status ] );
                        }
                    }
                    return this;
                }), abort:(function ( statusText ) {
                    var finalText = statusText || strAbort;
                    if ( transport ) {
                        transport.abort( finalText );
                    }
                    done( 0, finalText );
                    return this;
                }), state:(function () {
                    return state;
                }), always:(function () {
                    deferred.done( arguments ).fail( arguments );
                    return this;
                }), then:null, promise:(function ( obj ) {
                    return obj != null ? jQuery.extend( obj, promise ) : promise;
                }), pipe:(function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
                    var fns = arguments;
                    return jQuery.Deferred(function( newDefer ) {
                        jQuery.each( tuples, function( i, tuple ) {
                            var action = tuple[ 0 ],
                                fn = jQuery.isFunction( fns[ i ] ) && fns[ i ];
                            // deferred[ done | fail | progress ] for forwarding actions to newDefer
                            deferred[ tuple[1] ](function() {
                                var returned = fn && fn.apply( this, arguments );
                                if ( returned && jQuery.isFunction( returned.promise ) ) {
                                    returned.promise()
                                        .done( newDefer.resolve )
                                        .fail( newDefer.reject )
                                        .progress( newDefer.notify );
                                } else {
                                    newDefer[ action + "With" ]( this === promise ? newDefer.promise() : this, fn ? [ returned ] : arguments );
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        fns = null;
                    }).promise();
                }), done:(function () {
                if ( list ) {
                    // First, we save the current length
                    var start = list.length;
                    (function add( args ) {
                        jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                            var type = jQuery.type( arg );
                            if ( type === "function" ) {
                                if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                    list.push( arg );
                                }
                            } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
                                // Inspect recursively
                                add( arg );
                            }
                        });
                    })( arguments );
                    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
                    // current firing batch?
                    if ( firing ) {
                        firingLength = list.length;
                    // With memory, if we're not firing then
                    // we should call right away
                    } else if ( memory ) {
                        firingStart = start;
                        fire( memory );
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }), fail:(function () {
                if ( list ) {
                    // First, we save the current length
                    var start = list.length;
                    (function add( args ) {
                        jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                            var type = jQuery.type( arg );
                            if ( type === "function" ) {
                                if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                    list.push( arg );
                                }
                            } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
                                // Inspect recursively
                                add( arg );
                            }
                        });
                    })( arguments );
                    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
                    // current firing batch?
                    if ( firing ) {
                        firingLength = list.length;
                    // With memory, if we're not firing then
                    // we should call right away
                    } else if ( memory ) {
                        firingStart = start;
                        fire( memory );
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }), progress:(function () {
                if ( list ) {
                    // First, we save the current length
                    var start = list.length;
                    (function add( args ) {
                        jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                            var type = jQuery.type( arg );
                            if ( type === "function" ) {
                                if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                    list.push( arg );
                                }
                            } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
                                // Inspect recursively
                                add( arg );
                            }
                        });
                    })( arguments );
                    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
                    // current firing batch?
                    if ( firing ) {
                        firingLength = list.length;
                    // With memory, if we're not firing then
                    // we should call right away
                    } else if ( memory ) {
                        firingStart = start;
                        fire( memory );
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }), complete:(function () {
                if ( list ) {
                    // First, we save the current length
                    var start = list.length;
                    (function add( args ) {
                        jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                            var type = jQuery.type( arg );
                            if ( type === "function" ) {
                                if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                    list.push( arg );
                                }
                            } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
                                // Inspect recursively
                                add( arg );
                            }
                        });
                    })( arguments );
                    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
                    // current firing batch?
                    if ( firing ) {
                        firingLength = list.length;
                    // With memory, if we're not firing then
                    // we should call right away
                    } else if ( memory ) {
                        firingStart = start;
                        fire( memory );
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }), success:(function () {
                if ( list ) {
                    // First, we save the current length
                    var start = list.length;
                    (function add( args ) {
                        jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                            var type = jQuery.type( arg );
                            if ( type === "function" ) {
                                if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                    list.push( arg );
                                }
                            } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
                                // Inspect recursively
                                add( arg );
                            }
                        });
                    })( arguments );
                    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
                    // current firing batch?
                    if ( firing ) {
                        firingLength = list.length;
                    // With memory, if we're not firing then
                    // we should call right away
                    } else if ( memory ) {
                        firingStart = start;
                        fire( memory );
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }), error:(function () {
                if ( list ) {
                    // First, we save the current length
                    var start = list.length;
                    (function add( args ) {
                        jQuery.each( args, function( _, arg ) {
                            var type = jQuery.type( arg );
                            if ( type === "function" ) {
                                if ( !options.unique || !self.has( arg ) ) {
                                    list.push( arg );
                                }
                            } else if ( arg && arg.length && type !== "string" ) {
                                // Inspect recursively
                                add( arg );
                            }
                        });
                    })( arguments );
                    // Do we need to add the callbacks to the
                    // current firing batch?
                    if ( firing ) {
                        firingLength = list.length;
                    // With memory, if we're not firing then
                    // we should call right away
                    } else if ( memory ) {
                        firingStart = start;
                        fire( memory );
                    }
                }
                return this;
            }), status:0, statusText:"[Exception... \"Access to restricted URI denied\"  code: \"1012\" nsresult: \"0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)\"  location: \"file:///home/zen/ember/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js Line: 8526\"]"})
[15:46:25.156] uncaught exception: [object Object]
```

I understand that it's not to do with the endpoint or the JSON being fed in, as Ember is not even attempting to make a HTTP request. I am pretty stumped by this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit here is at the end of the error message:

`Access to restricted URI denied`

It's probably because you're running over the `file://` protocol. You should find a way to access your Ember App using `http://` e.g. `http://localhost:8080/`.

Be aware that you'll need to set up CORS headers if your AJAX endpoint is different to the host of that page. So you'll probably want to change your adapter specify no `host:` property (which should default to the current host).